# HTML/CSS Is this concept of using break points in media queries incorrect?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML/CSS/front end web design and I've just started using media queries to make the site more fluid and mobile/tablet friendly.

Is it better to use specific break points for certain devices? Such as a query at 375px for the iPhone 6 and one at 1024px for an iPad and so on.

Or, is it better to do it how I've done mine by styling the site on a widescreen desktop and then scaling the width down in my browser until the styling messes up, and using that point as a break point for a media query to sort out the styling for that width, and so on.

You'll see in my code examples.

To cut to the point, do I use specific queries for each device width or scale it for every width as I've done below?

Thanks.

```css
/* Global Styles ------------------- */

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgb(207, 207, 207);
  font: 1.1em/1.5 Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin:auto;
  overflow: none;
}

/* Navigation Bar ----------------- */

header {
  background: rgb(44, 45, 61);
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 30px black;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 8px black;
  border-bottom: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 1px;
}
nav {
  float: right;
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: silver;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: white;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
#active {
  color: white;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

/* Landing Showoff ------------ */

.landing h1,
.landing h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.landing h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.landing {
  background: url('https://placeimg.com/750/500/tech') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 75px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 8px black;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px -2px black;
}

/* Information Columns -------------- */

.info {
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding: 10px 10%;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
.info-border {
  border-top: solid grey 2px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.info h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}

/* Clearfix ------------------- */

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Media Queries ----------------- */

@media (max-width: 1345px) {
  .info {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .info-border {
    width: 80%;
    margin:auto;
    overflow: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .container {
    width: 85%;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 925px) {
  .container {
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 875px) {
  .container {
    width: 95%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 830px) {
  .info {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    list-style-position: inside;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 825px) {
  .container {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  .info {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-position: inside;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 745px) {
  .container {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .left {
    float: none;
  }
  .right {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="description" content="DESCRIPTION">
    <meta name="keywords" content="SEARCH, ENGINE, OPTIMIZATION">
    <meta name="author" content="NAME">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <header class="clearfix">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
          <h1><span class="highlight">Lorem</span> Ipsum</h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
           <ul>
            <li><a id="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section class="landing">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
    </section>

    <section class="info clearfix">
      <div class="info-border"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
          <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
            <li>Ipsum dolor lorem</li>
            <li>Dolor lorem ipsum</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
            <li>Ipsum dolor lorem</li>
            <li>Dolor lorem ipsum</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: most people build websites for small devices (phones) first, then build their way up using `min-width`. It greatly reduces the struggle of fighting dimensions. Larger frameworks follow this methodology including [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), [Foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/), and [Lightning](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/).

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. Any reasoning for this? Cheers I'll start learning Bootstrap I think :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mostly on the right track. It's far too complicated to cover every device specifically, especially when there are so many different devices at varying sizes, and they keep coming out with new sizes every year.

That said, the norm (which still *kind of* holds up) is that there are ~3 device ranges — phone, tablet, and desktop — which you should consider. I'd suggest remembering this as you build your design, and so that you don't wind up with a million different breakpoints as things grow. You can use a framework to look at what breakpoints they use, or continue as is, but pick a few different devices to test on in Chrome's [device toolbar](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports#device-specific_mode). (This last option is probably a little informative than resizing your window.)

Comment: Thanks, I have the Window Resizer plugin for Chrome. I think you're right that I should just use desktop, tablet and mobile. To be honest I should use a framework like Bootstrap but I'm following an online course and all I've learnt so far is CSS/HTML basics. Me trying to jump the gun haha. Thanks

Comment: @DannyFairbrass that sounds good, the bootstrap codebase is great to learn from, too.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well, you want to have a responsive design for your page. If you can, try to use bootstrap. More specific, their grid system. You can specify how much of the screen each section can use on each type of screen sizes.
For example, if you want it to occupy 40 % of the screen for laptops and full screen for tablets, you can use it like

More documentation, here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid
Hope it helps !

Comment: Yeah you're right I should be using a framework as it does the work for you and is more fluid than anything I'd ever build. Thanks.